# How do you combine multiple ffserver streams into a grid in real time?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, streaming, webm

I'm trying to set up a CCTV system with ffmpeg/ffserver/zoneminder and want a nice looking 4x4 grid without all the Java applet borders and window dongles on it, just a full screen 4x4 grid.  I've gotten ffserver to stream webm for browsers and mpg for zoneminder, but when I build a page with 16 webm videos embedded into it it stalls out after loading about 5 at once.  I'm looking for a way to take 16 live streams and combine them into a single live stream that is four times the width and height arranged in a grid.

I've tried using ffmpeg to handle this with the appropriate settings in /etc/ffserver.conf using the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i http://localhost:8090/0.webm -i http://localhost:8090/1.webm -i http://localhost:8090/2.webm -i http://localhost:8090/3.webm -i http://localhost:8090/4.webm -i http://localhost:8090/5.webm -i http://localhost:8090/6.webm -i http://localhost:8090/7.webm -i http://localhost:8090/8.webm -i http://localhost:8090/9.webm -i http://localhost:8090/10.webm -i http://localhost:8090/11.webm -i http://localhost:8090/12.webm -i http://localhost:8090/13.webm -i http://localhost:8090/14.webm -i http://localhost:8090/15.webm -filter_complex "
nullsrc=size=1280x960 [bg];
[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v0];
[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v1];
[2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v2];
[3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v3];
[4:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v4];
[5:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v5];
[6:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v6];
[7:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v7];
[8:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v8];
[9:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v9];
[10:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v10];
[11:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v11];
[12:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v12];
[13:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v13];
[14:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v14];
[15:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [v15];
[bg][v0] overlay=shortest=1 [bg];
[bg][v1] overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [bg];
[bg][v2] overlay=shortest=1:x=640 [bg];
[bg][v3] overlay=shortest=1:x=960 [bg];
[bg][v4] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [bg];
[bg][v5] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240 [bg];
[bg][v6] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=240 [bg];
[bg][v7] overlay=shortest=1:x=960:y=240 [bg];
[bg][v8] overlay=shortest=1:y=480 [bg];
[bg][v9] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=480 [bg];
[bg][v10] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=480 [bg];
[bg][v11] overlay=shortest=1:x=960:y=480 [bg];
[bg][v12] overlay=shortest=1:y=720 [bg];
[bg][v13] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=720 [bg];
[bg][v14] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=720 [bg];
[bg][v15] overlay=shortest=1:x=960:y=720" http://localhost:8090/all_webm.ffm
```

But it comes in at only a few FPS and isn't suitable for live streaming.

Does anyone know how to do this with ffmpeg, or if there is a program that can do it that plugs into ffserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling 16 streams, so your CPU has a hard job on it to convert. You seriously need enough CPU power to handle all that data.

I also see you are scaling each video. Scaling is a very time consuming process in a CPU. Maybe you can set up your camera streams to provide a scaled video already, so your CPU only needs to put them together.

You can also look for other options of encoding/decoding, because some encoders are like 10 times faster than the others.

Comment: I'm not sure why I had that scale in there, it was scaling to the same size as the inputs but removing it got me to 25FPS.

Comment: @Nick van Tilborg Question: I am not exactly at the same situation my scenario is where i am having streams from multiple sources and i want write these inputs to separate feeds (feed1,feed2..etc) ,while doing so i get all streams but video is not playing properly?